# Is every $k$-Lindelöf space an $\varepsilon$-space?

Tags: general-topology, lindelof-spaces

An $\omega$-cover $\mathscr U$ of a space $X$ is a collection of open sets so that $X \not\in\mathscr U$ and every finite subset of $X$ is contained in a member of $\mathscr U$. Similarly, a $k$-cover $\mathscr U$ of a space $X$ is a collection of open sets so that $X \not\in\mathscr U$ and every compact subset of $X$ is contained in a member of $\mathscr U$.

A space is an $\varepsilon$-space (aka $\omega$-Lindelöf) if every $\omega$-cover has a countable subset which is an $\omega$-cover. Likewise, a space is $k$-Lindelöf if every $k$-cover has a countable subset which is a $k$-cover.

In an effort to establish the relationships between these properties, one may wonder if there are any implications either way. For example,

> Is every $k$-Lindelöf space an $\varepsilon$-space?

As an initial attempt, one may start with an $\omega$-cover of $X$ and close it under finite unions to guarantee a $k$-cover of $X$. However, the countable subset which is a $k$-cover of the resulting $k$-cover may not correspond to an $\omega$-subcover of the given $\omega$-cover of $X$. So this argument doesn't work.

**Edit:** One approach occurred to me as I was writing the question. My posting here is to have a reference to include for https://topology.pi-base.org/ following the guidelines for references as spelled out at https://github.com/pi-base/data/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

If anyone knows of a place this is mentioned in the literature that I missed, I'd appreciate knowing where it occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, every $k$-Lindelöf space is a $\varepsilon$-space. The proof follows the same line of reasoning as the proof of Theorem 5 in https://doi.org/10.1007/s10114-005-0753-8.

What we actually show is that every finite power of a $k$-Lindelöf space $X$ is $k$-Lindelöf and, since every $k$-Lindelöf space is Lindelöf, we see that any $k$-Lindelöf space is Lindelöf in each of its finite powers. (The fact that every $k$-Lindelöf space is Lindelöf is stated without proof in the proof of Proposition 5 of https://doi.org/10.1016/j.topol.2005.07.015, and is pretty straight-forward. Just take an open cover and consider the cover formed by the finite unions from that open cover. The result is a $k$-cover so you can choose a countable subset which is a $k$-cover. Note that this corresponds to a countable subcover of $\mathscr U$.) The fact that being an $\varepsilon$-space is equivalent to being Lindelöf in each of its finite powers is a well-known result from https://doi.org/10.1016/0166-8641(82)90065-7.

> **Claim:** If $X$ is $k$-Lindelöf, then $X^m$ is $k$-Lindelöf for every positive integer $m$.

*Proof.* Let $X$ be $k$-Lindelöf and suppose $\mathscr U$ is a $k$-cover of $X^m$ for a positive integer $m$. By Lemma 3 of https://doi.org/10.1007/s10114-005-0753-8, we can let $\mathscr V$ be a $k$-cover of $X$ so that $\\{ V^m : V \in \mathscr V \\}$ refines $\mathscr U$. Then there is some $\\{V_n : n \in \omega\\} \subseteq \mathscr V$ that forms a $k$-cover of $X$. Let $U_n \in \mathscr U$, be so that $V_n^m \subseteq U_n$. To see that $\\{ U_n : n \in \omega \\}$ is a $k$-cover of $X^m$, let $K \subseteq X^m$ be compact. Note that the union of $\pi_{k}[K]$ for $1 \leq k \leq m$ is a compact subset of $X$ where $\pi_{k}$ is the usual projection mapping onto the $k^{\text{th}}$ coordinate. So we can find $n \in \omega$ so that $$\bigcup_{j=1}^m \pi_k[K] \subseteq V_n.$$ Hence, $K \subseteq V_n^m \subseteq U_n$. $\square$

Comment: You asked and answered your question immediately. I'm not sure this is necessarily against math.se guidelines or etiquette. However, maybe you could change the question slightly, by asking for alternative answers. Or state in your question what else you're hoping to gain by posting your question and answer here. See here for example: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question

Comment: @AdamRubinson Thank you for pointing me to that link. I have changed the answer to a community wiki answer to not gain reputation and have also updated the question to reflect my intention in the post.

Comment: @Adam, please read https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @StevenClontz I am already aware of that. What is your point?

Comment: It explicitly encourages users to ask and answer questions immediately, so you should consider not making suggestions to the contrary.